# Can I use two datasources in one query in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

In Grafana, I can query a DB (e.g., prostgres) and show the result in table;
I can also query the time series data from prometheus and show the result in table in a different query.

How can I join the results from these two queries?

I know if the data is from a single source, I can join them.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use 2 different datasources in one query.
But you can use 2 different datasources (that means also 2 queries) in one panel (e.g. table panel).
You can also join these 2 results from 2 different datasources in Grafana by using [join transformation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#join-by-field) - of course you need to have a field, which is common for both results.